# Visit m.google.com from regular computer

Tags: google-search, mobile

Is there a way to visit http://m.google.com from a regular browser? It detects non-mobile browsers and forwards them, but I'd like to view this site from a regular PC.

Comment: Set a User-Agent that looks "mobile"

Answer (score 1):

You need a "user agent" switcher, like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Chrome, go to the location of where the chrome.exe file was installed.

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\

Create a shortcut of the chrome.exe file.

Right-click on the shortcut and select Properties.

In the Target field, enter the following:

> "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3"

The user-agent string tells the site that you're "using" an iPhone and should load up the mobile version of the site without redirecting you to the regular desktop version.